# Problems with cifs/ntfs

Tags: linux

I've been working on setting up Transmission to download to my NAS, which has a shared NTFS directory.

I'm getting an error "Error: Permission denied (/mnt/ntfs/...)
[image]

I understand this has to do with something with permissions, but I have no idea how to fix it.

I tried to using

```
sudo chown -R focus:focus /mnt/ntfs/transmission
```

My main user on Pi is called "focus". Also tried doing same for "debian-transmission" user.

After entering it still shown that folder belongs to root.

```
ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root          0 Aug 25 08:55  transmission
```

This is what see from my W10 machine in terms of permissions, if that helps with diagnose.

[image]

Comment: Why NTFS? Linux permissions don't work on NTFS even with ntfs-3g installed. You'll need to mount it with the transmission user using uid=transmission-daemon on the mount command.

Comment: I tried doing same with NFS, but then transmission works fine, but my W10 machine has no rights to move around the files on the that I downloaded to the share, I have to do it manually via console, which is pain in bum with long filenames...

Comment: Mount an NFS share on your RPi. Run samba to make that a Windows share with universal permissions defined in samba.

Comment: As Dougie points out, using `chown` on an NTFS mount won't work.  The files will just be owned by whoever mounted it.

Comment: @Dougie I really a potato when it comes to linux. What do you mean by running Samba? Could you link somekind of guide I could follow along?

Comment: Samba is the way to share Linux data with Windows clients.

Comment: @Dougie Yeah I figured that out. I also think that the whole permission problem is now because of PLEX. It seems to be acquired the write/read permission for the folders I want move stuff to. Tried googling around, no results.